# How to check if given field caused a validation error in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I have category_id field in my Symfony2 form.
After calling `$form->bindRequest($this->request)` I want to check (inside a controller) if category_id caused an error. How can I do that? I found some solution that requires iterating over $form->getErrors() but it required some recursion. Is that some "built-in" way to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like...

```
$form['category_id']->hasErrors()
```